# Flask MongoEngine queryset in templates

Tags: flask, jinja2, mongoengine

I am building a small application with Flask and mongoengine.

In a simple view I have:

```
@app.route('/course/<slug>/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def course_detail(slug):
    course = Course.objects.get(slug=slug)


    return render_template(
        'course_detail.html',
        title='Course Detail -' + course.name,
        course=course,
   )
```

I want to iterate this data in the template but if I do:

```
{% for k, v in course %}{{ v }}{% endfor %}
```

I get `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

I also wanted to sum the values:

```
{{ course.values()|sum }}
```

With this I get:

```
UndefinedError: 'flask_mongoengine.BaseQuerySet object' has no attribute 'values'
```

So how should I iterate through querysets in Flask with mongoengine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Course.objects.get(slug=slug)` return document which is not `dictionary`.
So to get all object fields just use:

```
{% for field in course %}{{ course[field] }}{% endfor %}
```

There are `BaseDocument.__iter__()` return field names and you get values in jinja2 with `course[field]`.

But I advise you use `Course.objects(slug=slug).first()` instead `Course.objects.get(slug=slug)` if you didn't have `MultipleObjectsReturned` and `DoesNotExist` exceptions handlers.

You can't use `sum` filter, because it's use build in `sum` function which use iterable of numbers, but `BaseDocument.__iter__()` return field names.
So you can:

1. get sum and pass it to template.
2. write own jinja2 filter;
3. add special method for your document definition which will return fields sum;
4. add special method for your document definition which will retrun number fields list and use `sum` filter;

If you want get iterable object of courses then use just use `Course.objects(slug=slug)`.

Comment: Thanks! You have provided a lot of information here for me to explore as I become familiar with both Flask and MongoEngine. Very useful.